# Switch windows to different virtual space with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, shortcuts, virtual-desktop

How to achieve it? In the best case with native shortcut, otherwise looking for at least AHK solution

Comment: Have you done a search on one of the popular search engines, before posting the question?

Comment: Yes, I've did it, only results require mouse usage. AHK solution will probably be required